# Does "Natel" mean the same thing as "Handy" (cell phone) in German?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english, swiss-standard-german

Does "Natel" mean the same thing as "Handy" (cell phone) in German? Why and how?

Comment: Of course, "Handy" in German [doesn't mean](https://www.br.de/grips/faecher/grips-englisch/23-present-perfect-vokabeln-false-friends100.html) "handy" in English. To rephrase the question: "Does *Natel* in Swiss German mean the same as *Handy* in German (i.e., cell phone)?"

Comment: Of course, «Natel» is not Swiss German, but German – Swiss Standard German, to be more precise.

Comment: I believe there was a comment to the answer, earlier, that's now deleted, that pointed out that Duden lists the word *Natel*: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Natel. Did you look it up?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden

Comment: I also wonder how you not managed to find this just by googling.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is used that way in Switzerland. Note that you will most likely not be understood if you use the word outside of Switzerland. It is a Swiss Standard German word (cf. [Duden | Natel](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Natel)).

The origin is the Swiss brand NATEL ("Nationales Autotelefon") of Swisscom (or originally of the Swiss Mail & Telecommunications service PTT).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natel) has more.

Comment: As someone who lives in Switzerland, I'd also comment that Natel has become far less common with time. As shown by this Google Trends graph - https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=CH&q=natel,handy

Comment: Do the Swiss use any alternatives now to "natel", "mobil" and "handy"?

Comment: Most people use "Handy" when speaking Swiss German. Only a few people use "Natel", most of them are 50+ years old.

Comment: @user610620 `Do the Swiss use any alternatives now to "natel", "mobil" and "handy"?` - "mobil" should not be on that list. I have never heard any of my swiss fellows refer to their phone as "Mobil" or "Mobile". In fact, not even "Mobiltelefon" is used, which (I believe) is sometimes said in Germany. And no, there are no real alternatives. In my experience, ~95% say "Handy", the rest says "Natel".